# Failing CakePHP 2 Code Works After 'debug' Inserted

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

Ignore the fact that we need to update CakePHP 4 for a moment...

I've had the following scenario happen a dozen times over the last year. Code will refuse to work even though it's perfect, so I add a 'debug' to dump some information, and the code magically starts working. Even stranger, if I remove the 'debug', the code continues to work.

I thought it was just a quirk of my own laptop until a colleague said he added a 'debug' to our online development environment and the problem he was trying to solve fixed itself.

Finally, today I was trying to determine why a SQL-heavy section of code was taking far longer than it needed to and wasn't returning any info. I cleared by cache several times and even rebooted my laptop for maximum freshness – nothing helped. I added a bunch of 'debugs' and ran the code several times, then removed the 'debugs' and now the code is executing in 1/5th the time and it's displaying the data, which is a table of 400 rows with 12 columns each, nothing big.

Does anybody have any idea why adding a debug, reloading the page, then removing the debug, fixes code that was previously non-functional? Is there a way to prevent having to do this stupid trick in the first place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is certainly not a common problem, hence it's pretty much impossible for anyone to tell unless they by chance once had the same problem, and even then they'd also be just guessing, like anybody else here who has no access to the project, and thus cannot see the problem being reproduced.

Comment: All I can suggest is trying to figure how exactly your application behaves differently with and without `debug()` calls, for example they can cause output to be generated before headers are sent (including cookies), and thus change responses. Also they require enabling debug mode, which may change for example cache durations. Generating additional output can also change where possible memory related problems appear, and how exactly they present themselves. And of course make sure to have an eye on your server, DBMS, PHP, and application logs (all of them!).

Comment: My guess would be the Cake cache (not the browser cache). By enabling debug, everything in the Cake cache will expire and be renewed with good information. When you disable debug after that, that good information will still be in there, so it'll keep working.